# AWS Allow Cross-account EKS Cluster to Pull Images from ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, amazon-ecr

### Summary:

I'm looking to enable EKS nodes to pull images from an ECR registry from a different AWS project. I created an "AllowPull" policy in the desired ECR repository and set the principal of the policy to the ARN of the EKS cluster role, but node is unable to pull the image.

How should the policy be formulated in order to allow all nodes in an EKS cluster to pull from a cross-account ECR repository?

### Attempt Details:

- The ECR registry recourse name is:

  ```
  arn:aws:ecr:us-east-2:226427918358:repository/external-pull-test
  ```
- The EKS cluster that needs to pull the images has the following role attached:

  ```
  arn:aws:iam::02182452XXXX:role/aws-dev-eks-cluster-crpiXXXX091410594876160000000c
  ```
- The external ECR registry has the following policy JSON:

  ```
  {
      "Version": "2008-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Sid": "AllowPull",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                  "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::02182452XXXX:role/aws-dev-eks-cluster-crpiXXXX091410594876160000000c"
              },
              "Action": [
                  "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                  "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                  "ecr:DescribeImages",
                  "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                  "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
  ```
- The pod `ImagePullBackOff` error specifies that the user attempting to authenticate with the registry is this assumed role:

  ```
  arn:aws:sts::02182452XXXX:assumed-role/aws-dev-eks-cluster-crpiXXXX091410594876160000000c/i-0ea4f53b6dfdcxxxx
  ```

### Environment:

- Kubernetes: `v1.16.15-eks-e1a842`

### Additional Details:

Using the ARN of my user principal (cross-account) in the policy did allow me to pull images using docker locally. Using the ARN of the assumed role did enable the node to pull the image, but my understanding is that configuring the policy with a particular assumed role won't guarentee that the cluster nodes can consistently pull from the registry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another method is click on the "external-pull-test" repo on the ECR console, on the left panel under "Repositories" click on "Permissions", then click on "Edit" on the top right. You can add the account ID that needs to pull from this repo at "AWS account IDs". Check the permitted actions at the bottom "Actions" drop down box. "Save" and you should be able to pull.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm not very familiar with AWS IAM, so could you please explain what the "AWS account ID" be in this case? Is it the role ARN `arn:aws:iam::02182452XXXX:role/aws-dev-eks-cluster-crpiXXXX091410594876160000000c`?

Comment: `02182452XXXX` is the AWS account ID. Note it is the ID of the AWS account where the EKS resides that you will use. On the console if you click right top (the menu with account name and region), you should see the current AWS account ID too.