# AWS EKS: non-working cross-account ECR image pull, despite having correct permissions on 1) the EKS node and 2) the ECR repo

Tags: amazon-eks, http-status-code-403, amazon-ecr

What else, besides the following, is needed for an EKS node to be able to pull an ECR image from another account:

1. `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly` permission on the EKS node's Instance Profile
2. below permissions on the ECR repository:

   ```
   ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability
   ecr:BatchGetImage
   ecr:DescribeImages
   ecr:DescribeRepositories
   ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
   ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer
   ```

   EKS's account ID is listed under `Permissions > AWS Account IDs` for this ECR repository (as also answered in [AWS Allow Cross-account EKS Cluster to Pull Images from ECR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69926362/aws-allow-cross-account-eks-cluster-to-pull-images-from-ecr)).

`kubelet` currently reports

> pulling from host <ECR_URL> failed with status code [manifests <IMAGE_TAG>]: 403 Forbidden

Also checked that:

- the `<IMAGE_TAG>`, in the above error, exists.
- there isn't any `Deny` policy on the EKS node.

Given that the `403` status is returned, I presume that networking is OK as well.

One could reprovision the nodes, with SSH enabled, and then try f.e. `aws ecr get-login-password`. Is there a better way to investigate?

Comment: You could look at the cloudtrail logs.